# Sort the website dropdown list for users with less than 200 reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange, user-interface, stack-exchange-button

Why does the StackExchange website dropdown list randomly the sites I have <200 rep on? Please make the sites I have <200 rep on be sorted just like the sites I have >200 rep on.

Dropdown

[image]

Website list

[image]

Comment: Sorting only takes effect in sites where you have 200+ rep; below that, it's random.

Comment: @waiwai933 Can you explain why that is?

Comment: Oops! really! that answered it, but still this could be feature-request to sort even less than 200 reps.

Comment: That's a good idea, I will change the question

Comment: I guess it can be a reminder for the users about the Q&A sites where he has an account. The fact you noticed the order of those sites change shows the trick worked. `:-)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't feel that users have shown a strong "preference" for a site until they earn 200 reputation on it.

Therefore, we present the list in random order until you have at least 200 reputation -- this encourages cross-pollination in the network and helps users discover new and interesting sites as they browse around.

[image]

Remember too that you get +100 on every site once you cross the +200 threshold on any site in the network, so +200 is not very hard to achieve on many sites.

(and yes, the above is now automated, thanks to Kevin.)

Comment: What did you say was now automated?

Comment: @ambo the +100 bonus is automatic now.