# Why not add "my sites" to stack exchange menu?

Tags: feature-request

I was just wondering if it was a good idea to have a field called "my sites" or something similar.

Now, in the StackExchange menu you can find:

1. hot questions
2. all sites

(at least I have that)

And it's a bit of a slow search to find just the 3 sites I'm registered with.

So I think it would be a great idea to have these sites (or the feed of the 3) in a specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I like this, it's really a little redundant, as once you have >200 reputation on a site, it will sort to the top of the "all sites" tab.  (If you have >200 on multiple sites, they will be ordered by reputation, excluding the site you are on.)

[There is a request to make it sort sites you have <200 reputation on to the top as well as the sites you have >200 reputation on.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88617/sort-the-website-dropdown-list-for-users-with-less-than-200-reputation)

Comment: ok, i don't know that fact. thanks for the info.